# How do I add a combobox in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

How do I add a combobox in a word document without creating a form? Is there a possible way? I've seen comboboxes in Excel, is it possible in word?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Word "fields" could be what you're after

Comment: I have a table in a word document with all its values based on one colour, however this has to be done for 8 colors. Instead repeating myself, I want something that will change values when a color is picked.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write VBA (macro) code in the Document_New and 
Document_Open procedures.

The simplest method, if the contents of the list will always be the 
same, is to use something like

Private Sub Document_New()
With ComboBox1
.AddItem "one"
.AddItem "two" 
' etc. 
.ListIndex = 0 
End With 
End Sub

You'd need the same thing in Document_Open, because the combo box 
doesn't store the list in the document file when the document is 
closed.

If you need to get values from a database, see the combo box part of 
the article at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnwor...2/html/