# How to add entries to combobox in Word XP

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to follow the following instructions to add a combobox to a form and add some values to it for the user to pick: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/create-forms-that-users-complete-in-word-HP005230270.aspx

I've created a .dot and then dragged a combobox onto the document.  When I double-click on it though, it opens up the VBA editor.

Do I have to add the items programatically as per the following question [How do I add a combobox in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/147706/how-do-i-add-a-combobox-in-word) or is it possible to do this using the UI?  The other question/answer refers to creating a form.  Is there a step I've missed between creating a .dot to then create a form somehow before adding form elements to it?

Right clicking gives the following menu options:

- Cut
- Copy
- Paste
- properties
- View code
- Combo Box Object -> Edit or Convert
- Format Control
- Hyperlink

Choosing edit allows me to type some text onto the visible part of the control, but doesn't allow me to add multiple options

Right-clicking and selecting properties opens the following:

[image: properties]

Comment: Does it work if you right click and select properties rather than double click?

Comment: Updated question to show what happens when I select properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the searching I've done so far, it appears this can only be done programatically (at least in older versions of Word).

e.g. 
http://oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/combodrop_0100.html

> Your guess that you needed to add some code to populate your drop-down
>   combo box is quite correct. VBA allows you to assign a value to the
>   combo box's Value and Text properties (in reality, they're the same
>   property) from the user interface, which lets you add only a single
>   item to a drop-down combo box. This, of course, isn't terribly useful,
>   since presumably you're using the combo box to allow the user to
>   choose from among multiple items. This is precisely one of those
>   quaint features of the MSForms controls--in Microsoft's retail Visual
>   Basic product, it's very easy to populate a combo box at design time.
>
> In almost all cases, you want to populate the combo box before the
>   user sees it, so that the user can select from among the available
>   items. Fortunately, Word makes this easy. Whenever a document opens,
>   Word checks the code behind a Word document for the presence of a
>   procedure named Document_Open. If it is found, the code is executed.
>   (The procedure, incidentally, is called an event handler, since it's
>   automatically executed by Word in response to some event, in this case
>   the document's being opened by the user.)

VBA code now added and working, but somewhat surprised that there didn't appear to be a way to do this through the menus...